# No iOS project templates in MonoDevelop 2.8

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I used to work on MonoDevelop 2.6 with MonoTouch 4.2. It's cool and everything is fine.

Later, when MD 2.8 came out, I installed it with MD 2.6 side by side (just renamed MD 2.6 as MonoDevelop 2.6). But I can not load iOS projects. And, there is no iOS project templates showing up in new solution window.

I tried to uninstall Mono Framework, MD 2.6, 2.8 and MonoTouch and reinstall Mono Framework 2.10, MD 2.8 and MonoTouch 4.2, but still, no iOS project templates.

So, anyone can help?

Thanks.

EDIT: According to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1413, my problem would be related to case-sensitive issues. And it should be fixed in MD 2.8.1.

Comment: Where did you get your MonoDevelop 2.8 from?   This is very odd.

Comment: From http://monodevelop.com/. Yes, it's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still experiencing the problem where the MonoTouch templates are not showing up? If so, would you be interested in trying out a special build of MonoDevelop to help us track down the issue. I've been trying to reproduce the problem for the last hour or two with no success so I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening to some users. With your help I might be able to resolve this once and for all.

If you're interested, fire off an email to me and/or respond here and we can sort out some debug builds.

EDIT: Would you be able to follow the debugging steps on our issue tracker to provide us with more information so we can diagnose this: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1413

Comment: Actually, this problem could be re-doable. I tested on a new installed Lion hard drive, then installed XCode 4.2->Mono Framework->MD 2.8->MT 4.2.2, and I got no iOS project templates showed up in MD.

Answer (score 0):

Are the MonoTouch and Apple SDKs detected and/or configured correctly in the the Other->SDK Locations panel in MonoDevelop preferences?

Comment: That implies the addin isn't loading at all. Does it show up in the Addin Manager? Try removing ~/Library/Caches/MonoDevelop-2.7 and ~/Library/Caches/MonoDevelop-2.8

Comment: Does /Developer/MonoTouch exist?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, did you mean that only the Apple SDK option is visible in the panel, or only the Apple SDK is marked as having been detected? Also, could you please get the info tab from the MD about box and pastebin that somewhere?

Comment: I got this "SDK found at default location". Also, you can find my MD version info here: http://aaronmix.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Version-Info.txt

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded Xcode to 4.1. The Xcode install renamed the /Developer folder to /Developer-(null). MonoDevelop failed to load iOS projects after this change. Thanks to mhutch's comment, I moved my Monotouch install from /Developer-(null) to /Developer and restarted MonoDevelop to correct the problem.